# Time-barred list in redis

Tags: redis

It's easy to do a list in redis with a fixed size, by performing `ltrim` at the required size. However, how can one maintain a list that contains data that is time-barred, not size-barred.

E.g. how would I maintain a list of all `user_ids` that logged into my website in the last 10 mins? Please provide an illustrative example of the most efficient way to accomplish this. Maybe I'm approaching this with the wrong data-type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a sorted set instead of a list. Use unix timestamps as score of items.

To add an item in the Zset:

`ZADD myzet <current timestamp> item`

To retrieve the items of the last ten minutes, sorted by insertion time, older first:

`ZRANGEBYSCORE myzset (<current timestamp - 600 seconds> (+inf`

To get the newest first replace `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` with ZRANGEBYSCORE.

To remove the expired items:

`ZREMRANGEBYSCORE -inf (<current timestamp - 600 seconds>`